# FizzBuzz Problem - I failed to write logic with more functionality. I already explained in the Comment Section of Code

Tags: php, function, loops, fizzbuzz

My FizzBuzz application which counts from 1 to 100 and outputs either the corresponding number or if one of the following rules apply output the corresponding text.

Rules:

- dividable by 3 without a remainder -> Fizz
- dividable by 5 without a remainder -> Buzz
- dividable by 3 or 5 without a remainder -> FizzBuzz

I want to add this? Please refactor this code so that it can be extended in the future with other rules, such as

- "if it is dividable by 7 without a remainder output Bar"
- "if multiplied by 10 is larger than 100 output Foo"

You can uncomment if($i * 10 > 100) first and then see the result. I need exactly the same output when I removed this below code. But its compulsory is greater than 100 then it would be Foo, and follow the same structure for example at 30: it should be FizzBuzz not FizzBuzzFoo

My Code Is:

```
 class FizzBuzzEngine
    {
       public function run($limit = 100)
    {
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $limit; $i++) {
        $output = '';
        if ($i % 3 == 0) {
            $output .= "Fizz";
        }
        if ($i % 5 == 0) {
            $output .= "Buzz";
        }
        
        if($i * 10 > 100){
            $output = "";
            $output = "Foo";
        }
        if($i % 7 == 0 ){
            $output = "";
            $output.= "Bar";
        }
        if (empty($output)) {
            $output = 'None';
        }
        echo sprintf('%d: %s', $i, $output . PHP_EOL);
     }
  }
}

$engine = new FizzBuzzEngine();
$engine->run();
```

Comment: "But its compulsory is greater than 100 then it would be Foo" and "for example at 30: it should be FizzBuzz not FizzBuzzFoo" seem to be at odds with each other. Also, "You can uncomment", but nothing is commented out.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/PInfb - You never get FizzBuzz, because the first number that's divisible by 3 and 5 is 15, and that multiplied by 10 is 150. Therefore it's overwritten by Foo. If it's evenly divisible by 7, you reset $output and set it to Bar.

Comment: Thanks for your guideline and hint of reset $output and again make value to Bar.

Comment: It helps me and now result is as per my requirement. Thank You